# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddControllers'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.0 project running fine with the following startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();            
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Now I want to move this setup to another project, to serve as a Common dll to be used by dozens of other ASP.NET Core 3.0 projects where all of them will execute the startup with calling just `services.Configure();`, considering that `Configure` will be an extension method created by me.

For this, I've created another project with the following .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And the following class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyCommon.Extensions
{
    public static class MyIServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
        {
            public static IServiceCollection Configure(this IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddCors();
                services.AddControllers();
                return services;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the following build error:

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddControllers'

As I've already added the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addcontrollers?view=aspnetcore-3.0), I don't understand why the `AddControllers` method couldn't be found.

Comment: `AddControllers` was added in 3.0, but you're using 2.2 in your .NET Standard project. You can't target .NET Standard _and_ use ASP.NET Core 3.0 components - ASP.NET Core only runs on .NET Core. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference) might be helpful.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thanks. If you transform this comment into an answer, I will be able to mark it as helpful.

Comment: @Manpreet Kaur answer helps, but i'm curious how Newtonsoft.Json can affect extension method that is in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions?

Answer (score 17):

I got the same with Asp .netcore 3.0.
Resolved it by adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package.

Comment: This actually helped, but i'm curious how Newtonsoft.Json can affect extension method that is in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions`?

Comment: This also worked for me. I have no idea why, but it's been a long day, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Services.AddControllers was added in 3.0 core not in 2.2 and in addition, it recommended using Newtonsoft.Json when using .NET Core 3.0+ due to problems with the serialization: Nuget.