# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddControllers' even added newtonjson

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Core 5.0.1 project and planning to create authentication on swagger UI but I encounter some issues on the services controller. Which is the error code below. Regarding this I have seen an issue similar to me in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256217/iservicecollection-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-addcontrollers) but my issue is not resolve even added the NewtonsoftJson. Any ideas on this kind of issue.

> Error CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddControllers' and no accessible extension method 'AddControllers'
> accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson;


[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ABSRestService.App_Start.Startup1))]

namespace ABSRestService.App_Start
{
    public class Startup1
    {
       public Startup1(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigurationServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image of Error]

Comment: Shown namespaces are correct. Make sure `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll` is referenced by the project where this code is invoked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addcontrollers?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: What is ASP.NET Core 4.7.2? Are you using ASP.NET Core with .NET Framework? What version of ASP.NET Core are you actually using? If you're using < 3.x, there's no `AddControllers` and if you're using .NET Framework, there's no ASP.NET Core 3.x+.

Comment: @Nkosi I think reference it correct but is checking it again

Comment: @KirkLarkin Hmm i check on dotnet --info it says 5.0.1 version as per if it is with net framework sorry I am not know how to check it but base on the dotnet --info above

Comment: Start over. Your project is mixing ASP.NET with ASP.NET Core. When choosing your project, make sure you pick ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET. One uses .NET Core, the other uses .NET Framework. Choose the one that uses .NET Core.

Comment: @Andy Sir question with that can I just create for the .Net core and connect it to my current project with ASP.net only or that is not possible?

Comment: It's not possible. They are two entirely different frameworks.

Comment: @Andy that is sad to hear but thanks sir for the help appreciate it. Do you have any suggestion btw with an authentication that can be use on Asp.net only?

Answer (score 0):

At first Install-Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`and then

Try this, it should work.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: Hi sir already installed it but same issues :(

Comment: Hi sir I have same issues because after Service no reference for AddControllers() I updated the question with a screenshot